# Strange URL linking in PHP -- do not understand

Tags: php, ajax

The code I'm working with has a strange URL naming convention, and I'm not sure how it works.

```
var url = "##SITE_URL##user/validate_username";
```

This url calls the PHP function 'validate_username' located inside user_php_files! I'm not sure how it works.

In the configuration

```
define("SITE_URL",'http://'.SITE_DOMAIN_NAME);
```

I tried creating a PHP function called 'create_username' inside the same user_php file and then using AJAX to call it (with the same naming convention)

```
$.post('##LBL_SITE_URL##user/create_username',{id:1},function(res) {...
```

But the function is not even called.

Why is there the ## sign? And how does it call a function from inside the PHP script?

Comment: What kind of Software do you use? Without any further information we cannot help you.

Comment: Could it be `##SITE_URL##` is supposed to be replaced with the real site url at some point, but isn't?

Comment: in the config/constants.php, found that 

define("SITE_URL",'http://'.SITE_DOMAIN_NAME);

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that's some sort of template and someone is using a string replace to search for ##SITE_URL## to be replaced by the actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an `.htaccess` rewrite rule issue.

Comment: this is listed as a poor quality answer on stack overflow system and that's why I'm here. To maintain the quality of the content of this platform, use the comments instead of answers when you are not actually answering the questions.